# Why does mysql LIKE query sometimes fail to return results?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Environment Details (XAMPP) 
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.3
Server version: 5.6.11 - MySQL Community Server

I have a search bar to search out new users that I have no relationship established with. When I add search parameters I am sometimes getting results and sometimes am not getting results.

Why does the following occur?

Search for: "Sarah T" returns info on user Sarah Testname

While Search for: "Sarah Test" returns nothing.

I use trim() and str_replace() to remove the white characters. ie " Sar  a h" becomes "Sarah"

In the Database:

```
firstname | lastname
Sarah     | Testname
Robert    | Richards
```

Using the following Stored Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_contact_list_new`//

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_contact_list_new`(
    IN _id        bigint(20),
    IN _args      varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
    IF _args IS NULL THEN
        SELECT u.* FROM user_user_relationship AS uur 
        RIGHT JOIN user AS u 
        ON uur.user_id_one = _id AND u.user_id = uur.user_id_two 
        WHERE u.user_id != _id AND uur.status IS NULL;
    ELSE
        SET @args = CONCAT("%",_args,"%"); 
        SELECT u.* FROM user_user_relationship AS uur 
        RIGHT JOIN user AS u 
        ON uur.user_id_one = _id AND u.user_id = uur.user_id_two 
        WHERE u.user_id != _id AND uur.status IS NULL AND 
       (u.firstname LIKE @args OR u.lastname LIKE @args OR (u.firstname + u.lastname) LIKE @args OR u.username LIKE @args OR u.email LIKE @args) ;      
    END IF;
END//
```

Soemtimes I can add random characters in the middle ie sarzqtes and Sarah Testname is returned.

Is this a bug with the MySQL Like query? Or is it my query? Whichever it is - could you explain to me why?

These issues also occured on phpmyadmin mysql console.

```
call get_contact_list_new(1,"saraht")
```

returns info about Sarah Testname

```
call get_contact_list_new(1,"sarahtes")
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(u.firstname + u.lastname) LIKE @args
```

should be:

```
CONCAT(u.firstname, " ", u.lastname) LIKE @args
```

`+` is numeric addition, not string concatenation. And you need to put a space between the first and last names, otherwise you'll get `SarahTestName`, which won't match `%Sarah Testname%`.

Comment: Ha I should of noticed that since I used it for the args. Mind you I thought it was somehow different. Many Thanks!